# jQuery - animations, queues, stop() and notifications

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user clicks any link on website, I want to show him a notification, which will disappear in 2 seconds. But when he clicks next link when previous notice is still visible, next notification shouldn't be showed and visible notice from first click should be visible for 2 seconds after second click.

How to do it?

I tried a lot of things, jQuery's delay(), jQuery's stop(), setTimeout() etc. but always notice disappears in 2 seconds after first click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/719oxjpu/1/

Basically :

```
var timeOut;

function checkBeforeShow($div) {
    if ($(".notification").length == 0) {
        $('body').append($div);
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.notification').remove();
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.notification').remove();
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

1. Set timeout for removing notice in 2 sec.
2. If clicked when the notice is present, clear timeOut and reset it to 2sec.
3. On timeout remove notice.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot that `clearTimeout` function exists :)